# How to fetch POS-tags from NLTK using Stanford Parser?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, stanford-nlp

I have used the StanfordParser with NLTK on Python. it gives me the following output:

```
(ROOT
    (S
        (NP (NNP Python))
        (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT a) (JJ lovely) (NN language)))
        (. !)))
```

But I want to have a list like this:

```
[['Python', 'NNP'], ['is', 'VBZ'], ['a', 'DT'], ['lovely', 'JJ'], ['language', 'NN']]
```

I want all the Noun Phrases. What Should I do?

Comment: If you only want POS tags, then there's no need to run a parser, since POS tagging is a preprocessing step to parsing anyway. Have a look at NLTKs POS taggers, eg. the [StanfordPOSTagger](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag.stanford).

Comment: @lenz StanfordPOSTagger doesn't give me the noun phrases.

Comment: In your example output there are no noun phrases. I suggest you first figure out what exactly you need, then post a new question and delete this one here (changing the problem statement through an edit is frowned upon on this site).

Comment: pardon me dear @lenz. i didn't mention that i want the noun phrases, so i edited my question after your first comment. stackoverflow gives me the option to edit my question. why not to?

Comment: Editing is fine, but you shouldn't change what you are asking for, because people might answer your original questions and after your changes they'd appear not to fit anymore. Also, your post is still inconsistent: In your example output (the "list you want to have") there is nothing about noun phrases. Please make up your mind what you really need, include what you tried so far (take the code from your "answer") and rephrase the question in a consistent way.

Comment: Just to be clear about what is unclear: Your original question sounded like all you need are POS tags. Then you said you need noun phrases, so it looks like you need chunks. Yet your title and examples are all about parsing, although it is not needed for either of the two tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see are methods for NLTK Trees: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree.html

This most likely would do it:

```
parser = StanfordParser(model_path="lib/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
parsed = parser.raw_parse("update Office 365")
next(parsed).pos()
```

Returns: 
[('update', 'VB'), ('Office', 'NNP'), ('365', 'NNP')]